# Why is the recipe apache::default executed when I am only using the recipe apache::mod_jk?

Tags: ruby, apache, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

This is the only line in my recipe

```
include_recipe "apache2::mod_jk"
```

This calls the mod_jk recipe found in the opscode [apache2 cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/apache2), that for the sake of simplicity I'll write here:

```
package 'libapache2-mod-jk' do
  case node['platform_family']
  when 'rhel', 'fedora', 'suse'
    package_name 'mod_jk'
  else
    package_name 'libapache2-mod-jk'
  end
end

apache_module 'jk'
```

To my understanding this will only install mod_jk and apache, but apache won't be configured with chef because I am not using the apache2::default... However this doesn't happen, apache2 gets installed and configured using the Chef tempaltes.

How does this work? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the definition apache_module 'jk' calls apache::default here: https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/apache2/blob/master/definitions/apache_module.rb#L21

You could make your own recipe that installs the package.

More info on cookbook definitions: http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbook_definitions.html